# SQL Stored procedure formatting error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is the first time i am writing stored procedure on SQL. I have multiple optional search parameters. I have done this in php query as below
Note : This is not the original code

```
     $query = " 

SELECT  CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE trntypename END AS trntypename,
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201510' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201510],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201511' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201511],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201512' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201512],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201601' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201601],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201602' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201602],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyyMM') = '201603' THEN AmountDue END) AS [201603],
        SUM(AmountDue) Total FROM RAccounts_Receivable WHERE ";

        if ($rep != "") {
            $query .= "(SalesmanGroupName=:rep)";
            if (($market != "") || ($agent != "") || ($warehouse != "") || ($customername != "") || ($regionalname != "")) {
                $query.=" and ";
            }
        }

        if ($market != "") {
            $query .= "(bptypename=:market)";
            if (($warehouse != "") || ($customername != "") || ($regionalname != "")) {
                $query.=" and ";
            }
        }

        if ($warehouse != "") {
            $query .= "(warehousename=:warehouse)";
            if (($customername != "") || ($regionalname != "")) {
                $query.=" and ";
            }
        }

        if ($customername != "") {
            $query .= "(SupplierName=:supplier)";
            if ($regionalname != "") {
                $query.=" and ";
            }
        }

        if ($regionalname != "") {
            $query.= "(territoryname=:territory) ";
        }

       if (($rep != "") || ($market != "") || ($agent != "") || ($warehouse != "") || ($customername != "") || ($regionalname != "")) {
            $query.=" AND ";
        }

        $query .=" datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
GROUP BY ROLLUP([trntypename])
ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 0 END
";
```

what i want is to convert this to SQL stored procedure. when i try to do that am getting an code formatting error. pls check

```
USE  CustomReports

GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE arReports(@rep AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@market AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
DECLARE @CaseQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(datecreated,''yyyy/MM'') = ''<<dateval>>'' THEN AmountDue END) AS [<<dateval>>]',
        @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT  @SelectQuery = COALESCE(@SelectQuery + ',', '') + REPLACE(@CaseQuery, '<<dateval>>', FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM'))
FROM    [dbo].[RAccounts_Receivable]
WHERE   datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
GROUP BY FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM')
ORDER BY FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM')

SET @Sql = '
        SELECT  CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN ''Total'' ELSE trntypename END AS trntypename,
         ' + @SelectQuery + ',
          SUM(AmountDue) Total
        FROM RAccounts_Receivable
        WHERE'

   BEGIN
    IF (@rep <>'''') 
        SET @sql = @sql + '([SalesmanGroupName] = ''+@rep +''
        IF (@market <> '') 
             SET @sql = @sql + ' AND'
   END    

   BEGIN
    IF (@market <>'')  
        SET @sql = @sql + ''([bptypename] = ''+ @market +''

   END

    AND datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
    GROUP BY ROLLUP([trntypename])
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
'
EXEC (@Sql)

RETURN
```

problem is withing below part

```
SET @Sql = '
            SELECT  CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN ''Total'' ELSE trntypename END AS trntypename,
             ' + @SelectQuery + ',
              SUM(AmountDue) Total
            FROM RAccounts_Receivable
            WHERE'

       BEGIN
        IF (@rep <>'''') 
            SET @sql = @sql + '([SalesmanGroupName] = ''+@rep +''
            IF (@market <> '') 
                 SET @sql = @sql + ' AND'
       END    

       BEGIN
        IF (@market <>'')  
            SET @sql = @sql + ''([bptypename] = ''+ @market +''

       END

        AND datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
        GROUP BY ROLLUP([trntypename])
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    '
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Properly an issue with unclosed string literals in the building

Comment: yes this should be problem with unclosed string. how can i debug that.

Comment: print your @sql and execute it, so you can check what are going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use Dynamic sql is by using parameterization that can be done by using sp_executesql like mentioned below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE arReports
@rep AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  = null,
@market AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @paramlist nvarchar(max)
declare @nl char(3) = char(13) + char(10)
Declare @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @debug bit = 0
SELECT  @SelectQuery = COALESCE(@SelectQuery + ',', '') + REPLACE(@CaseQuery, '<<dateval>>', FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM'))
FROM    [dbo].[RAccounts_Receivable]
WHERE   datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
GROUP BY FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM')
ORDER BY FORMAT(datecreated,'yyyy/MM')

set @sql = '
SELECT  CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN ''Total'' ELSE trntypename END AS trntypename,
         ' + @SelectQuery + ',
          SUM(AmountDue) Total
        FROM RAccounts_Receivable
        WHERE 1=1' + @nl

if @rep is not null 
begin
set @sql = @sql + ' and [SalesmanGroupName]  = @rep' + @nl
end

if @market is not null 
begin
set @sql = @sql + ' and [bptypename] =  @market' + @nl
end

set @sql = @sql +  ' AND datecreated >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 7,0)
    GROUP BY ROLLUP([trntypename])
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING(trntypename) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'

set @paramlist = '@rep NVARCHAR(MAX),
@market NVARCHAR(MAX)'

if @debug = 1 
Begin
Print @sql
end

exec sp_executesql @sql,@Paramlist,@rep,@market
end
```

Let me know if this helps.

I have used the parameter @debug to check the @sql wording. Simply assign @debug = 1 when you want to check the value of @sql.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I execute Stored procedure 'EXEC arReports @rep=Alex,@market=ARIZONA' and getting the error as 'Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.'

Comment: My Mistake. I have changed the @paramlist from varchar to Nvarchar. This should work now.

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if you find the solution helpful.

Comment: Glad... I could help